# Espaçamento entre imagens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Não estou conseguindo colocar espaço entre as imagens usando esta `<div>`

```
<div class="col-xs-12">espaço entre as imagens</div>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="servicos">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="templatemo-line-header">
        <div class="text-center">
          <hr class="team_hr team_hr_left hr_gray" /><span class="txt_darkgrey">Nossos Serviçoss</span>
          <hr class="team_hr team_hr_right hr_gray" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- box -->
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <a><img src="http://tudosobrecachorros.com.br/wp-content/uploads/cachorro-independente.jpg" alt="Serviços de Limpeza" title="Cooparseg Cooperativa Paranaensa de Segurança"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>SERVIÇOS DE LIMPEZA</span>
          <p>Temos uma das melhores metodologias do mercado e todo equipamento nescessário para executar o trabalho de limpeza e conservação com excelência, visando facilitar a vida do cliente e tornar o ambiente agradavél e limpo, proporcionando conforto
            e simplificando o dia dia dos nossos clientes.</p>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <!-- box -->

      <div class="col-xs-12">espaço entre as imagens</div>

      <!-- box -->
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <a><img src="http://tudosobrecachorros.com.br/wp-content/uploads/remedios-proibidos-cachorro-766x526.jpg" alt="Serviços de Limpeza" title="Cooparseg Cooperativa Paranaensa de Segurança"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>SERVIÇOS DE PORTARIA</span>
          <p>Utilizando um dos melhores métodos de treinamento do mercado e atualizando a mão de obra a anualmente, dispomos dos melhores profissionais para atender os mais diversos tipos de portaria e proporcionar maior sensação de segurança e confiança
            para o ambiente contratado.</p>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <!-- box -->

      <!-- box -->
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <a><img src="http://tudosobrecachorros.com.br/wp-content/uploads/precos-de-cachorro.png" alt="Serviços de Limpeza" title="Cooparseg Cooperativa Paranaensa de Segurança"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>SERVIÇOS DE RECEPÇÃO</span>
          <p>Sabemos que uma calorosa e educada saudação de boas vindas no primeiro contato é primordial para um bom atendimento e comunicação com os clientes, com isso nós dispomos dos melhores e mais bem treinados profissionais para recepcionar todos de
            forma eficaz e educada.</p>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <!-- box -->

      <!-- box -->
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <a><img src="ihttp://petiko-blog-novo.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/fatos-sobre-as-orelhas-do-seu-cachorro-6.jpg" alt="Serviços de Limpeza" title="Cooparseg Cooperativa Paranaensa de Segurança"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>SERVIÇOS DE PORTARIA VIRTUAL</span>
          <p>Realizamos serviços desde o nível residencial, atendendo casas, condomínios e edifícios ate o comercial como empresas e industrias. Promovendo manutenção de forma eficaz preventiva, garantimos rejuvenescimento e revitalização de todas as áreas
            verdes e jardins de seu terreno.</p>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <!-- box -->

      <!-- box -->
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <a><img src="https://static.tudointeressante.com.br/uploads/2015/10/raz%C3%B5es-para-mimar-o-seu-cachorro-1.jpg" alt="Serviços de Limpeza" title="Cooparseg Cooperativa Paranaensa de Segurança"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>SERVIÇOS DE COPA</span>
          <p>Dispomos de copeiras e garçons da mais alta competência para realizar as mais diversas atividades com discrição e eficiência, tanto para eventos ou rotinas diárias. Além de servir e manter o estoque em ordem eles também tem o compromisso de
            manter tudo higienizado.</p>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <!-- box -->

      <!-- box -->
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <a><img src="http://barkpost.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/whatthepup.png" alt="Serviços de Limpeza" title="Cooparseg Cooperativa Paranaensa de Segurança"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>SERVIÇOS DE JARDINAGEM</span>
          <p>Realizamos serviços desde o nível residencial, atendendo casas, condomínios e edifícios ate o comercial como empresas e industrias. Promovendo manutenção de forma eficaz preventiva, garantimos rejuvenescimento e revitalização de todas as áreas
            verdes e jardins de seu terreno.</p>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <!-- box -->

      <!-- box -->
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <a><img src="http://dicas.guiamais.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/nomes-de-cachorro.jpg" alt="Serviços de Limpeza" title="Cooparseg Cooperativa Paranaensa de Segurança"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>SERVIÇOS DE CFTV</span>
          <p>Circuito Fechado de Televisão (CFTV), é um sistema de TV que distribui sinais de câmeras colocadas em locais específicos, para um determinado ponto de supervisão. O CFTV não é aplicado somente com propósitos de segurança e vigilância, mas também
            em escolas, empresas e até na medicina.</p>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <!-- box -->

      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="templatemo-gallery-category" style="font-size:16px; margin-top:80px;">
        <div class="text-center">

        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta colocar um margin nessa sua div. Criei a class `espaco` que coloca uma margin de 60px encima e abaixo da div. Segue o código abaixo.

```css
.espaco{
    margin: 60px 0;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="servicos">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="templatemo-line-header">
        <div class="text-center">
          <hr class="team_hr team_hr_left hr_gray" /><span class="txt_darkgrey">Nossos Serviçoss</span>
          <hr class="team_hr team_hr_right hr_gray" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- box -->
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <a><img src="http://tudosobrecachorros.com.br/wp-content/uploads/cachorro-independente.jpg" alt="Serviços de Limpeza" title="Cooparseg Cooperativa Paranaensa de Segurança"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>SERVIÇOS DE LIMPEZA</span>
          <p>Temos uma das melhores metodologias do mercado e todo equipamento nescessário para executar o trabalho de limpeza e conservação com excelência, visando facilitar a vida do cliente e tornar o ambiente agradavél e limpo, proporcionando conforto
            e simplificando o dia dia dos nossos clientes.</p>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <!-- box -->

      <div class="col-xs-12 espaco">espaço entre as imagens</div>

      <!-- box -->
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <a><img src="http://tudosobrecachorros.com.br/wp-content/uploads/remedios-proibidos-cachorro-766x526.jpg" alt="Serviços de Limpeza" title="Cooparseg Cooperativa Paranaensa de Segurança"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>SERVIÇOS DE PORTARIA</span>
          <p>Utilizando um dos melhores métodos de treinamento do mercado e atualizando a mão de obra a anualmente, dispomos dos melhores profissionais para atender os mais diversos tipos de portaria e proporcionar maior sensação de segurança e confiança
            para o ambiente contratado.</p>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <!-- box -->

      <!-- box -->
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <a><img src="http://tudosobrecachorros.com.br/wp-content/uploads/precos-de-cachorro.png" alt="Serviços de Limpeza" title="Cooparseg Cooperativa Paranaensa de Segurança"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>SERVIÇOS DE RECEPÇÃO</span>
          <p>Sabemos que uma calorosa e educada saudação de boas vindas no primeiro contato é primordial para um bom atendimento e comunicação com os clientes, com isso nós dispomos dos melhores e mais bem treinados profissionais para recepcionar todos de
            forma eficaz e educada.</p>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <!-- box -->

      <!-- box -->
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <a><img src="ihttp://petiko-blog-novo.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/fatos-sobre-as-orelhas-do-seu-cachorro-6.jpg" alt="Serviços de Limpeza" title="Cooparseg Cooperativa Paranaensa de Segurança"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>SERVIÇOS DE PORTARIA VIRTUAL</span>
          <p>Realizamos serviços desde o nível residencial, atendendo casas, condomínios e edifícios ate o comercial como empresas e industrias. Promovendo manutenção de forma eficaz preventiva, garantimos rejuvenescimento e revitalização de todas as áreas
            verdes e jardins de seu terreno.</p>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <!-- box -->

      <!-- box -->
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <a><img src="https://static.tudointeressante.com.br/uploads/2015/10/raz%C3%B5es-para-mimar-o-seu-cachorro-1.jpg" alt="Serviços de Limpeza" title="Cooparseg Cooperativa Paranaensa de Segurança"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>SERVIÇOS DE COPA</span>
          <p>Dispomos de copeiras e garçons da mais alta competência para realizar as mais diversas atividades com discrição e eficiência, tanto para eventos ou rotinas diárias. Além de servir e manter o estoque em ordem eles também tem o compromisso de
            manter tudo higienizado.</p>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <!-- box -->

      <!-- box -->
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <a><img src="http://barkpost.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/whatthepup.png" alt="Serviços de Limpeza" title="Cooparseg Cooperativa Paranaensa de Segurança"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>SERVIÇOS DE JARDINAGEM</span>
          <p>Realizamos serviços desde o nível residencial, atendendo casas, condomínios e edifícios ate o comercial como empresas e industrias. Promovendo manutenção de forma eficaz preventiva, garantimos rejuvenescimento e revitalização de todas as áreas
            verdes e jardins de seu terreno.</p>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <!-- box -->

      <!-- box -->
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <a><img src="http://dicas.guiamais.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/nomes-de-cachorro.jpg" alt="Serviços de Limpeza" title="Cooparseg Cooperativa Paranaensa de Segurança"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>SERVIÇOS DE CFTV</span>
          <p>Circuito Fechado de Televisão (CFTV), é um sistema de TV que distribui sinais de câmeras colocadas em locais específicos, para um determinado ponto de supervisão. O CFTV não é aplicado somente com propósitos de segurança e vigilância, mas também
            em escolas, empresas e até na medicina.</p>
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <!-- box -->

      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="templatemo-gallery-category" style="font-size:16px; margin-top:80px;">
        <div class="text-center">

        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12"><p></div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a melhor maneira seja usar a classe default `.row` do Bootstrap por fora do seu BOX e colocar nela um `margin`

**CSS**

```
<style>
    .row {
        margin-top: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- box -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <a><img src="http://placeskull.com/100/100" alt="Serviços de Limpeza" title="Cooparseg Cooperativa Paranaensa de Segurança"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>SERVIÇOS DE JARDINAGEM</span>
            <p>Realizamos serviços desde o nível residencial, atendendo casas, condomínios e edifícios ate o comercial como empresas e industrias. Promovendo manutenção de forma eficaz preventiva, garantimos rejuvenescimento e revitalização de todas as áreas verdes e jardins de seu terreno.</p>
        </div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- box -->
```

**Execute em "Página Toda" para ver melhor**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Ensintech</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-mobile.css">


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

    <style>

.row {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
    </style>
 
 </head>
 
 <body>

        <div id="servicos" >
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="templatemo-line-header" >
            <div class="text-center">
            <hr class="team_hr team_hr_left hr_gray"/><span class="txt_darkgrey">Nossos Serviçoss</span>
            <hr class="team_hr team_hr_right hr_gray" />
            </div>
            </div>
            
            <!-- box -->
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <a><img src="http://placeskull.com/100/100" alt="Serviços de Limpeza" title="Cooparseg Cooperativa Paranaensa de Segurança"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span>SERVIÇOS DE LIMPEZA</span>
                            <p>Temos uma das melhores metodologias do mercado e todo equipamento nescessário para executar o trabalho de limpeza e conservação com excelência, visando facilitar a vida do cliente e tornar o ambiente agradavél e limpo, proporcionando conforto e simplificando o dia dia dos nossos clientes.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- box -->
            
                    <div class="col-xs-12">espaço entre as imagens</div>
            
            <!-- box -->  
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <a><img src="http://placeskull.com/100/100" alt="Serviços de Limpeza" title="Cooparseg Cooperativa Paranaensa de Segurança"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span>SERVIÇOS DE PORTARIA</span>
                            <p>Utilizando um dos melhores métodos de treinamento do mercado e atualizando a mão de obra a anualmente, dispomos dos melhores profissionais para atender os mais diversos tipos de portaria e proporcionar maior sensação de segurança e confiança para o ambiente contratado.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- box -->
            
            <!-- box -->
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <a><img src="http://placeskull.com/100/100" alt="Serviços de Limpeza" title="Cooparseg Cooperativa Paranaensa de Segurança"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span>SERVIÇOS DE RECEPÇÃO</span>
                            <p>Sabemos que uma calorosa e educada saudação de boas vindas no primeiro contato é primordial para um bom atendimento e comunicação com os clientes, com isso nós dispomos dos melhores e mais bem treinados profissionais para recepcionar todos de forma eficaz e educada.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- box -->
            
            <!-- box -->
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <a><img src="http://placeskull.com/100/100" alt="Serviços de Limpeza" title="Cooparseg Cooperativa Paranaensa de Segurança"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span>SERVIÇOS DE PORTARIA VIRTUAL</span>
                            <p>Realizamos serviços desde o nível residencial, atendendo casas, condomínios e edifícios ate o comercial como empresas e industrias. Promovendo manutenção de forma eficaz preventiva, garantimos rejuvenescimento e revitalização de todas as áreas verdes e jardins de seu terreno.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- box -->
            
            <!-- box -->
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <a><img src="http://placeskull.com/100/100" alt="Serviços de Limpeza" title="Cooparseg Cooperativa Paranaensa de Segurança"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span>SERVIÇOS DE COPA</span>
                            <p>Dispomos de copeiras e garçons da mais alta competência para realizar as mais diversas atividades com discrição e eficiência, tanto para eventos ou rotinas diárias. Além de servir e manter o estoque em ordem eles também tem o compromisso de manter tudo higienizado.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- box -->
            
            <!-- box -->
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <a><img src="http://placeskull.com/100/100" alt="Serviços de Limpeza" title="Cooparseg Cooperativa Paranaensa de Segurança"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span>SERVIÇOS DE JARDINAGEM</span>
                            <p>Realizamos serviços desde o nível residencial, atendendo casas, condomínios e edifícios ate o comercial como empresas e industrias. Promovendo manutenção de forma eficaz preventiva, garantimos rejuvenescimento e revitalização de todas as áreas verdes e jardins de seu terreno.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- box -->
            
            <!-- box -->
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <a><img src="http://placeskull.com/100/100" alt="Serviços de Limpeza" title="Cooparseg Cooperativa Paranaensa de Segurança"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span>SERVIÇOS DE CFTV</span>
                            <p>Circuito Fechado de Televisão (CFTV), é um sistema de TV que distribui sinais de câmeras colocadas em locais específicos, para um determinado ponto de supervisão. O CFTV não é aplicado somente com propósitos de segurança e vigilância, mas também em escolas, empresas e até na medicina.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- box -->
            
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="templatemo-gallery-category" style="font-size:16px; margin-top:80px;">
            <div class="text-center">
            
            </div>
            </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: resolvi com uma gambiarra <p>

Comment: <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12"><p></div>
</div>

Comment: @VanderleiFeyth não acho a melhor forma para resolver isso, mas se te atendeu... Imagine se no futuro vc quiser aumentar um pouco mais, vai sair colocando `<p>` em todos os lugar? E pior, se vc quiser menos espaço, como vai colocar algo com a altura menor que um `<p>`?

Comment: me passe um email que envio o site pra vc dar uma analizada e me ajudar a fazer do modo certo se possível obrigado

Comment: @VanderleiFeyth não existe modo certo. O amigo da outra resposta também deu uma solução, vc mesmo fez a sua gambeta e funcionou. O certo e vc avaliar o que funciona melhor para o seu projeto e como ele vai se comportar a longo prazo e se o cliente vai te pedir para mudar algo que vc não pode no futuro... Estude mais sobre CSS, Bootstrap e Boas Praticas que vc rapidinho pode tomar suas próprias decisões da forma mais correta.

Comment: OK Muito Obrigado!!!